# Create a CoffeeScript range with a length instead an endpoint?

Tags: coffeescript, range

I want to create a CoffeeScript range (like `[4...496]`) but using a length instead of an end range. This can be done with a loop like

```
myNum = getBigNumber()
newArray = ( n + myNum for n in [0...50] )
```

but I'm wondering if there is range-related shortcut that I'm missing. Is there something like

`[getBigNumber()...].length(50)` available in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
range = [myNum...myNum + 50]
```

**Edit:** As mu points out in the comments, CoffeeScript will add some complexity whether you use the snippet above or the original code. If performance is an issue, it might be better to drop down to plain JS for the loop (using backticks in the CoffeeScript code).

Assuming you want an ascending (i.e. low to high) range, you can do:

```
myNum  = getBigNumber()
length = 50
range  = new Array length
i      = 0
`for(; i < length ; i++) { range[i] = i + myNum }` # raw, escaped JS
```

[It's *a lot* faster](http://jsperf.com/cs-range-generation) than CoffeeScript's way of doing things, but note that CoffeeScript's range syntax also supports creating descending ranges by just flipping the boundary values. So CoffeeScript is (as always) easier on the eyes and simpler to work with, but raw JS is 3.5x faster in my test.

Comment: But understand that there's still a loop and a function call hidden behind that so there might be better ways when the range is large.

Comment: @muistooshort True. The loop's unavoidable, though, since JS doesn't support ranges natively. If you want a populated array, like in the question's code, that array must be created and populated somewhere. The function call that CoffeeScript creates could be skipped, though, that's true. But the larger the range, the less the calling overhead will matter relative to the loop itself.